# React Native: Drawing text that precisely fits within a given rectangle

Tags: react-native

I am seeking to port an android application which requires a high level of precision for drawing text.

Given a rectangle with precise dimensions in pixels, I wish to draw text that exactly fits within that rectangle, disregarding any descent or ascent. In other words, the physical pixels of the text must be flush against the rectangle border.

This means that for a given rectangle, the font size depends upon the letters that are drawn. For example, "Ag" will have a smaller font size than "aa" because space is needed for the ascent and descent.

Note this is a non-trivial task even with native android. (If it isn't possible to do this directly with react native, I suppose I could use my already-written native component and figure out the iOS side later.)

Comment: ? There's no relation between other rectangles. There's only one rectangle. We want to fit text exactly within that rectangle. The text changes. The rectangle stays the same. Depending upon what the text is, the font size differs. One rectangle. I could spend some time making pictures, but is that really unclear?

Comment: I did not say that "images, diagrams and code snippets etc" do not help. I did not expect your help. I said the time invested to draw pictures would be wasted because (1) the concept is utterly simple and clear in the first place; (2) someone not understanding it would be unable to help anyway; (3) the question is likely to go unanswered anyway. Please stop trolling and go away.